# How do I pull nested data into a bar chart using D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

http://bl.ocks.org/sconnors37/712bf691cefc1a1cb987/e9ae1b459c18fc15b5eb2c9b2fdb46c5f4a6e3ff

there is my gist file, you can see the data has the structure:

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Al Montoya",
      "saves": 155
},
{
  "name": "Alex Stalock",
  "saves": 147
},
{
  "name": "Anders Lindback",
  "saves": 124
},
{
  "name": "Anton Khudobin",
  "saves": 214}]}
```

etc.

I'm trying to pull this into my d3 bar chart so that "saves" is along the Y axis and "name" is along the x axis. When I edit the data to remove the "children" enclosure, everything works fine. What do I need to edit so that the chart pulls from within the children enclosure in this .json file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what's happening here is that the `data` parameter in your d3.json callback function looks at the top level of the JSON file, by default. In this case that is just the "children" array of objects. Since you need to use the objects inside that, I think if you create a new variable that drills down to that array specifically, that should help. Try simply adding this before the x.domain function:

```
var data = data.children;
```

Also, I don't think you need to put "type" as a parameter of the d3.json method, and that might be tripping up the request for the JSON data. I might just delete that so that line reads:

```
d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
```